# Meaning of Concentration parameters. Example of Dirichlet Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I would like to ask about the meaning of concentration parameters. Why are they called concentration parameters, how to infer them?

For example $(X_1,X_2)\sim \operatorname{Dirichlet}(a_1,a_2).$ The parameters $a_1,a_2$ are regarded as concentration parameters.

We know that the marginal distribution of $X_1$ or $X_2$ is a beta distribution with parameters
$X_1\sim \operatorname{Beta}(a_1,a_2)$ similar for $X_2$.

Suppose that we have a measurable partition $\left \{ A,A^{c} \right \}.$ I've read that the probability $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\in A)$ is distributed as $\operatorname{Beta}(a_1(A),a_2(A_c))$ and the expectation of $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\in A)$ can be calculated easily as $\frac{a_{1}(A)}{a_1(A)+a_2(A^c)} = \frac{a_1(A)}{(a_1+a_2)(\mathbb{R})}.$

Thus it is evident that the $a_1,a_2$ work as measures and are additive set functions.

Hence, from my understanding a concentration parameter works as a measure which calculate the volume/importance/mass of a particular set. From the expectation we can see that is measures the mass of the set $A$ that we are interested on, divided by the overall mass of the partition.

Also, the Dirichlet Process, which again uses the concetration parameters that we refered previously, is a special case of the Polya Tree. Thus, the parameters of the Beta distribution used on the Polya Tree can also be regarded as concentration parameters i.e measures???

Answer (score 2):

I'm only going to answer a small part of this here.

The Dirichlet distribution is the probability measure
\begin{align}
& \frac{\Gamma(a_1+\cdots+a_p)}{\Gamma(a_1)\cdots\Gamma(a_p)} x_1^{a_1-1} \cdots x_{p-1}^{a_{p-1}-1} (1 - x_1-\cdots-x_{p-1})^{a_p-1} \, \big(dx_1\cdots dx_{p-1}\big) \\[8pt]
& \qquad \text{for } x_1,\ldots,x_{p-1},1-x_1-\cdots-x_{p-1} \ge 0.
\end{align}
The concentration parameter is $A=a_1+\cdots+a_p.$ It is called the concentration parameter because it measure the extent to which probability is concentrated near the mean (the mean is $\frac{(a_1,\,\ldots\,,a_p)}{a_1+\cdots+a_p}$).

Thus when $A$ is large, the nearly all of the probability is very close to the mean.

The Beta distribution is the distribution of the first component in the special case in which $p=2.$ Its mean is $\mu = \dfrac{a_1}{a_1+a_2}.$ Its variance is $\dfrac{\mu(1-\mu)}{a_1+a_2+1} = \dfrac{\mu(1-\mu)} {A+1}.$ Thus the bigger the concentration parameter $A,$ the smaller the variance.